# Calculate$ (n+m-1)C_n \mod 10^9+7$ efficiently

Tags: combinatorics, modular-arithmetic

I want to calculate $(n+m-1)C_n \mod 1000000007$. where $n$ can be between $1$ and $10^9$. $m$ will not exceed $30$. How do I calculate it efficiently.

Comment: That number is more readable as $10^9+7$. In particular $n$ is always less than it.

Comment: yeah n is always less than the modulo

Comment: This question is an attempt to cheat in a programming competition http://www.codechef.com/TCFS15P/ . "Learner" has posted four questions here today from the same competition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the standard expression
$$
  \binom nk=\frac {n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)}{k!}
\text{ whence }
  \binom {n+m-1}m=\frac {(n+m-1)(n+m-2)\ldots n}{m!},
$$
while computing modulo $N=10^9+7$. You do the division using the [modular inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of $1,2,\ldots,m$ modulo $N$, which you can easily compute and tabulate. For $n$ very close to $N$ the numerator may contain a $0$, which will then also be the result, but this does not matter; the main point is the denominator cannot be $0$.