# Calculate $\binom{n}{k}\pmod{10^6+3}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

I want to calculate the value of the following:

$$\binom{n}{k}\pmod{10^6+3}$$

$10^6+3$ is prime if it may help.

What is the math behind this? I can only understand basic modular arithmetic.

Comment: Is there a apecific $n$ and $k$ you want this for? Because otherwise I don't think there's any good trick to it, other than straight-forwart modular multiplication and division, using the definition $C(n, k) = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.

Comment: @Arthur n and k can be anything. Nothing has been specified about them.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967620/calculate-nm-1c-n-mod-1097-efficiently?rq=1) is a link to a very similar question, and the answer to your question should be along the same lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can optimize the arithmetic mod $\,n=10^6+3\,$ by noting that $\,\color{#c00}{10^6\equiv -3},\,$ so we can compute remainders mod $\,10^6\,$ quickly via $\ a_0+a_1 \color{#c00}{10^6}+ a_2 \color{#0a0}{10^{12}}+\cdots \equiv a_0\color{#c00}{-3} a_1 + \color{#0a0}{9 } a_2 +\,\cdots $

Further, we  reduce multiplication to $3$-digit multiplication as follows

$$ (a + b\,10^3)(c + d\,10^3) \,\equiv\, ad\color{#c00}{-3}bd + (ad+bc)\, 10^3$$

That's the same product rule as in $\,\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]\,$   since $\, (10^3)^2 \equiv \color{#c00}{-3},\,$ so $\,10^3\,$ behaves like $\,\sqrt{\color{#c00}{-3}}$